# Min Normalization by condition

Tags: r, indexing, normalization

I have a dataset below that has sales data and other data by week broken out by group:

```
df

  Market  Week Sales  diff_data1    another2
1      1     1     5          30         -40
2      1     2     4           7          -8
3      1     3     7         100           9
4      1     4    11          92          50
5      2     1     8           0           8
6      2     2     5           0          14
7      2     3     8           9          98
8      2     4     1           3           3
```

My goal is to normalize the data two different ways: mean normalization and min normalization. Mean normalization is done to the sales data whereas min normalization is done to the non-sales. I think I have the mean normalization correct but the min normalization is a bit more tricky because I have conditions on the data being selected. Below is what I have currently.

```
##Function to standardizing variables
group = "Market"
date = "Week"

##Function to standardize sales by dividing by the standard deviation of sales
normalized_mean <- function(x){
  return(x/(sd(x)))
}

##Function to standardize variables by subtracting min
##Used for non-sales data
normalized_min<-function(x){
  out<- ifelse(x>0, ((x-min(x)) / sd(x)),
               ifelse(x<0, ((x+max(x)) / sd(x)), 
                      ifelse(x==0, 0,0)))
  return(out)
}

if (!("Sales" %in% colnames(df))){
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_min)
} else {
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_mean)

}
```

The current output of this is:

```
df_index

  Market  Week Sales  diff_data1   another2
1      1     1 1.62        0.655     -1.07  
2      1     2 1.29        0.153     -0.213 
3      1     3 2.26        2.18       0.240 
4      1     4 3.55        2.01       1.33  
5      2     1 2.41        0          0.178 
6      2     2 1.51        0          0.311 
7      2     3 2.41        2.12       2.17  
8      2     4 0.302       0.707      0.0666
```

The output should be this:

```
  Market  Week Sales  diff_data1    another2
1      1     1 1.62        0.501     0.26679  
2      1     2 1.29            0     1.12053
3      1     3 2.26         2.02     1.30729
4      1     4 3.55         1.85     2.40114 
5      2     1 2.41            0     7.93342
6      2     2 1.51            0     13.9334
7      2     3 2.41        2.121     97.9334
8      2     4 0.302       0.707     2.93342
```

My issue is this formula below.

How do I make the conditions work for this sort of example? It looks like it isn't taking the conditions of `x>0`, `x<0`, and `x==0` into account.

```
normalized_min<-function(x){
  out<- ifelse(x>0, ((x-min(x)) / sd(x)),
               ifelse(x<0, ((x+max(x)) / sd(x)), 
                      ifelse(x==0, 0,0)))
  return(out)
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with removing exclamation mark before "Sales", I think you have a typo:

```
if ("Sales" %in% colnames(df)){
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_min)
} else {
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_mean)

}
```

Output:

```
  Market  Week Sales diff_data1 another2
   <int> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1     1 0.323      0.502    0.267
2      1     2 0          0        1.12 
3      1     3 0.969      2.03     1.31 
4      1     4 2.26       1.85     2.40 
5      2     1 2.11       0        0.111
6      2     2 1.21       0        0.244
7      2     3 2.11       2.12     2.11 
8      2     4 0          0.707    0
```

This of course depends on what you really want.

In your description, it seems that it should calculate normalized mean (which is indeed what you get also in your output), but from your example it seems that whenever there is Sales in names, it should start calculating the normalized minimum.

If you remove the "Sales" column from your dataset, it also works fine with your initial function:

```
df <- df[,-3]


if (!("Sales" %in% colnames(df))){
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_min)
} else {
  df_index<-df %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(!!sym(group)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-one_of(!!group,!!date)), normalized_mean)

}

  Market  Week diff_data1 another2
   <int> <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1     1      0.502    0.267
2      1     2      0        1.12 
3      1     3      2.03     1.31 
4      1     4      1.85     2.40 
5      2     1      0        0.111
6      2     2      0        0.244
7      2     3      2.12     2.11 
8      2     4      0.707    0
```